# Is it possible to define a new custom signed attribute for CAdES?

Tags: pki, cms, rfc6979, cades

Is it possible to introduce a new *signed attribute* in the CMS Advanced Signature format (RFC 5126) for a custom data type? I want to include location data from GPS or Galileo and extend CAdES for my thesis.

I would appreciate it if you can provide me with some directions if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, attributes are identified by their ASN.1 Object IDs. You can use the `{joint-iso-itu-t(2) uuid(25)}` arc by generating a unique UUID (a.k.a. GUID) without needing to register, and parse it according to ITU-T-Rec-X.667 for use.